# Do I wrap the text element correctly?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created a wrapper around [Text](https://wix.github.io/react-native-ui-lib/docs/Text/) element:

```
export type PoppinsTextProps = PropsWithChildren<TextProps>

export default function PoppinsText(props: PoppinsTextProps) {

    return React.cloneElement(<Text {...props} />, { style: styles.text }, props.children);

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
        fontFamily: "Poppins-Medium"
    }

});
```

It works as expected, for example:

```
<PoppinsText text20>Hello</PoppinsText>
```

As you can see, I can pass the same properties on the wrapper as well as on the [Text](https://wix.github.io/react-native-ui-lib/docs/Text/).

The question is would you wrap the [Text](https://wix.github.io/react-native-ui-lib/docs/Text/) element in the same way as I do?

Comment: I really dont see a reason to not do this the same way

Comment: Even if you implement a wrapper, why to use clone instead of normal render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. we don't need to call `cloneElement` for wrapping a component, we can just return the Text component with the props.

```
export default function PoppinsText(props: PoppinsTextProps) {
    const {style, ...otherProps} = props
    return <Text {...otherProps} style={StyleSheet.flatten([style, styles.text])} />
}
```

We would use `cloneElement` if we want to touch the children or input component props.

For example, have different props provided by different container:

```
const ReverseContainer = () => {
  const newStyle = { color: "red" };
  const RenderChildren = () =>
    React.Children.map(props.children, (child) => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        style: StyleSheet.flatten([props.childrenStyle, newStyle]),
      });
    });
  return <Card>{<RenderChildren />}</Card>;
};
```

BTW, maybe you just want to define your preset:
https://wix.github.io/react-native-ui-lib/foundation/style

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a difference between `Stylesheet.flatten` vs just using the array of styles?

Comment: @Horst your provided code is pretty unclear and unformatted.

Comment: @Moistbobo It is my own practice when massaging a component style. The input props usually is a style id, there would be problems when modifying it.

Comment: @softshipper can't format it with my mobile.